# How to tell if a heap is serialized or not by its HANDLE?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, heap-memory

Say, if I call [`GetProcessHeaps`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366571(v=vs.85).aspx) in my process to get a list of heaps that it uses. Having a heap `HANDLE` how can I tell if such heap was created with the [`HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE` flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366599(v=vs.85).aspx) or not?

Comment: If nobody has a better solution, you could hook the `HeapCreate` and `HeapDestroy` functions in order to track this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

While not a definite answer, you can call [`HeapQueryInformation(HeapCompatibilityInformation)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366703(v=vs.85).aspx) and if it returns 2 then it is serialized because MSDN says this about HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE:

> The low-fragmentation heap (LFH) cannot be enabled for a heap created with this option

I don't know if there is even a undocumented API to get the flags but for debugging purposes you can access the internal heap structure directly:

```
void DumpHeapType_Win8_x86(HANDLE hHeap)
{
    typedef struct {
        UINT32 Unknown1[2];
        UINT32 Sig;
        UINT32 Unknown2[1];
        void*Unknown3[2]; //LIST_ENTRY?
        void*Unknown4[1+1+1+1+2];
        UINT32 Unknown5[1+1+1+1];
        UINT32 Flags;
    } HEAP_HDR;
    typedef struct {
        UINT32 Unknown1[2];
        UINT32 Sig;
        UINT32 Unknown2[1];
        void*Unknown3[2]; //LIST_ENTRY?
        HEAP_HDR*pHdr;
    } HEAP_THING;
    HEAP_THING *pThing = (HEAP_THING*) hHeap;
    if (hHeap && pThing->Sig == 0xffeeffee)
    {
        HEAP_HDR *pHdr = (HEAP_HDR*) pThing->pHdr;
        if (pHdr->Sig == 0xffeeffee)
        {
            printf("Flags=%#x Serialized=%d\n", pHdr->Flags, !(pHdr->Flags & HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE));
        }
    }
}

void playwithheaps()
{
    HANDLE hHeap;
    DumpHeapType_Win8_x86(hHeap = GetProcessHeap());
    DumpHeapType_Win8_x86(hHeap = HeapCreate(0, 0, 0)); if (hHeap) HeapDestroy(hHeap);
    DumpHeapType_Win8_x86(hHeap = HeapCreate(HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, 0, 0)); if (hHeap) HeapDestroy(hHeap);
    DumpHeapType_Win8_x86(hHeap = HeapCreate(HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE|HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS, 0, 0)); if (hHeap) HeapDestroy(hHeap);
}
```

On my Windows 8 machine this gives me the following output:

```
Flags=0x2 Serialized=1
Flags=0x1002 Serialized=1
Flags=0x1003 Serialized=0
Flags=0x1007 Serialized=0
```

but the heap structure layout might be different on other versions so you would just have to test carefully...

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but this is hardly a solution. What if the heap is not a low-fragmentation one?

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Did you get it yourself from reversing the heap APIs?

Comment: @c00000fd I did not really reverse much of the API. Some Windows versions have public symbols for the HEAP struct and the rest you can probably figure out by just dumping the handle memory in DWORD chunks and looking for things that look like pointers and/or flags.

Comment: On WinXP it seems like it goes straight to a smaller header with a signature of 0xeeffeeff and flags right after the signature so clearly you need to test on each version you support...

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I noticed that covfefe signature too.